# Using Pointers to Pointers to add nodes to a queue

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, queue

I read that Linus Torvalds interview where he uses double indirection to elegantly remove nodes from a linked list. I have a linked-list-based queue I want to convert to using double indirection to add nodes to the front of the list. There is an annoying condition where if the queue is empty, you have do something different than when it's non-empty.
Here's the code for the queue:

```
struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

struct queue {
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
};

void init_queue(struct queue *queue)
{
  queue->head = NULL;
  queue->tail = NULL;
}

void enqueue(struct queue *queue, struct node *node)
{
  if(queue->head == NULL) {
    queue->head = node;
    queue->tail = node;
  } else { 
    queue->tail->next = node;
    queue->tail = node;
  }
}
```

I want to convert it to something like this:

```
struct queue {
    struct node *head;
    struct node **tail;
};
void init_queue(struct queue *queue)
{
    queue->head = NULL;
    queue->tail = &queue->head;
}

void enqueue(struct queue *queue, struct node *node)
{
    (*queue->tail) = node;
    (*queue->tail)->next = node;
}
```

I can't figure out why it segfaults because I don't have a debugger handy. I haven't wrote C code in a while, and I need a refresher on double pointers it seems.

Comment: Your implementation isn't really making sense. If the queue is really empty, why would the `tail` of the null head be a pointer to the pointer to the head? Also, your new `enqueue` doesn't make any sense. You are setting the tail of the existing `queue` pointer to `node` and then setting that element's next pointer also to `node`. If you want a doubly linked list, why not just make the `node` have a `prev` and `next` pointer? Did you draw some pictures of your desired data structure, with some arrows, to see what makes sense before you coded it?

Comment: you don't have null checks and that for me is a BUG .and there are plenty of those.

Comment: I don't think it is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: `(*queue->tail)->next = node;` -->> `queue->tail = &node->next;`

Comment: BTW: things will be much simpler if you dont need to maintain a separate Queue structure containing the head & tail pointers.